# Understanding Prisma upsert

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma

I am trying to use a one to many relationship in Prisma and am confused. My goal is that when creating an athlete it is assigned a team and likewise the team is updated to show all athletes assigned to it. My resolver is shown below.

```
async function signUpUser(parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
    let password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10)

    const team = await prisma.team({ id: args.team })

    const user = await prisma.createUser({
        ...args,
        password,
        team: { connect: { id: team.id } }
    })
    //create special user based on user type from args
    switch(args.userType) {
        case "ATHLETE":
            createAthlete(user, prisma)
            break
        case "COACH":
            createCoach(user, prisma)
            break
        case "HEAD_COACH":
            createHeadCoach(user, prisma)
            break
        case "PARENT":
            createParent(user, prisma)
            break
        default:
            createAthlete(user, prisma)
    }

    return {
        user
        }
    }

    async function createAthlete(user, prisma) {

    const athlete = await prisma.createAthlete({
       user: { connect: { id: user.id } }
    })

    return athlete
   }
```

This code almost works how I would like it. The user is set a team and an athlete. However in my datamodel I want the team they are stored to to show all the athletes that are assigned under that team. I believe I need to use the upsert method but do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function createAthlete(user, team, prisma) {

    const athlete = await prisma.createAthlete({
       user: { connect: { id: user.id } }
    })

    const updatedTeam = await prisma.updateTeam({
        where: { id: team.id },
        data: {
            athletes: {
                connect: {
                    id: athlete.id,
                }
            }
        },
    })
    return {athlete, updatedTeam}
}
```